# MySQL: select table records where related table has empty match

Tags: mysql, matching, multiple-tables, not-exists

I have two tables with related information. "RoodCMS_prodQuants" and "RoodCMS_albums". These look as follows:

**RoodCMS_prodQuants:**

This table is a product quantity table. The combination idnr-prodID is unique. idnr refers the ID of an order in another table, prodID refers to idnr in "RoodCMS_albums"

```
-------------------------------------------------
idnr    | prodID    | kwantiteit
------------------------------------------------
2       | 2         | 2
3       | 1         | 1
4       | 1         | 2
4       | 2         | 2
5       | 3         | 1
```

**RoodCMS_albums:**

For administrative purposes, I only delete a record here if it is flagged as "to-be-deleted" (gepubliceerd = '-1'), and if there are no entries related to it anymore in the previous table (records from RoodCMS_prodQuants with the prodID as idnr in RoodCMS_albums). That's because I'd like to keep information like price, name until the last order containing this product is deleted.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
idnr  | gepubliceerd  | ... name, price, quantity-in-stock, etc...
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2     | 1             |
3     | 1             |
4     | -1            |  <---- this one is flagged to be deleted
1     | 1             |
```

In this case, I want to select the idnr of each record that does not have any corresponding records under the same prodID. For the tables that I displayed here, that means idnr='4' is a candidate to be selected, as there is no record with prodID='4'.

I tried a couple of queries to collect the records that match my criteria.

```
SELECT r1.idnr 
FROM RoodCMS_albums AS r1, RoodCMS_prodQuants AS r2 
WHERE r1.gepubliceerd='-1' AND r1.idnr = r2.prodID 
GROUP BY r1.idnr HAVING SUM(r1.kwantiteit) = 0
```

... and:

```
SELECT r1.idnr 
FROM RoodCMS_albums AS r1, RoodCMS_prodQuants AS r2 
WHERE r1.gepubliceerd='-1' AND r1.idnr = r2.prodID 
GROUP BY r1.idnr HAVING COUNT(r2.prodID) = 0
```

Both return an empty set of rows, whereas I aim for selecting idnr='4' from RoodCMS_albums. Could someone help me with writing a query that does return the result I aim for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left outer join` (or `not in` or `not exists`).  You should learn to use proper, explicit `join` syntax -- such habits would help you when you encounter an issue like this.  The query is more like:

```
SELECT r1.idnr 
FROM RoodCMS_albums r1 LEFT JOIN
     RoodCMS_prodQuants r2 
     ON r1.idnr = r2.prodID 
WHERE r1.gepubliceerd = '-1' and r2.ProdId is NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for writing a better query. This works indeed. In addition, thanks for the advice! I'll dig into it! :)